# Mongo Architecture Efficiency

Tags: mongodb

I am currently working on designing a local content bases sharing system that depends on mongoDB. I need to make a critical architecture decision that will undoubtably have a huge impact on query performance, scaling and overall long term maintainability.

Our system has a library of topics, each topic is available in specific cities/metropolitan areas. When a person creates a piece of content it needs to be stored as part of the topic in a specific city. There are three approaches I am currently considering to address these requirements (And open to other ideas as well).

**Option 1** (Single Collection per Topic/City):
Example: a collection name would be TopicID123CityID456 and each entry would obviously be a document within that collection.

**Option 2** (Single Topic Collection)
Example: A collection name would be Topic123 and each entry would create a document that contains an indexed cityID.

**Option 3** (Single City Collection)
Example: A collection name would be City456 and each entry would create a document that contains an indexed topicID

When querying the DB I always want to build a feed in date order based on the member's selected topic(s) and city. Since members can group multiple topics together to build a custom feed, option 3 seems to be the best, however I am concerned with long term performance of this approach. It seems option 1 would be the most performant but also forces multiple queries when needing to select more than one topic.

Another thing that I need to consider is some topics will be far more active and grow much larger than other topics which will also vary by location.

Since I still consider myself a beginner with MongoDB, I want to make sure the general DB structure is the most ideal before coding all of the logic around writing and retrieving the data. And I don't know how well Mongo Performs with hundreds of thousands if not millions of documents in a collection thus my uncertainty in approach.

From experience which is the most optimal way of tackling the storage and recall of this data? Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE: June 22, 2016**
It is important to note that we are starting in a one DB server environment to start. @profesor79 provided a great scaling solution once we need to move to a multi-server (Sharded) environment.

Comment: This is an opinionated question. I'd suggest you to do your own research and choose what is most suitable to your needs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from your 3 proposal I will pickup number 4 :-)

Having a one collection sharded over multiple servers.
As there could be one collection `TopicCity`, `we could have a one for all topics and one foll all cities.

Then collection `topicCities` will have all documents sharded.

[image]

Sharding on key `{topic:1, city:1}` will allow to balance load thru shard servers and enytime you will need to add more power you will be able to add shard to cluster.

[image]

Any comments welcome!

Comment: Thanks for putting this much effort into your response. That is certainly a great long term solution and I think we will most likely adopt an approach that will let us move into this type architecture when our data grows large enough. As of right now we have to start with one server.